# How can i use apache web service to rewrite URL?

Tags: reverse-proxy, apache2, proxypass

I have configured apache2 web server on my lan server and now I am configuring virtual host. My objective is to replace the local IP-address in place apache host IP in url.

For example :

I have installed apache web server on 172.30.17.102, when I call url `http://172.30.17.102/Proxy1/paramater/list` , than it should be go to `http://1.224.0.30:8080/dashboard/paramater/list`.
I tried below configuration in virtual host setting...

```
ProxyPass /Proxy1/^ http://1.224.0.30:8080/dashboard/$
ProxyPassReverse /Proxy1/^ http://1.224.0.30:8080/dashboard/$
```

I am new to apache web server. Please help me to find what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quoted config segment seems syntactically improper. Even if it would be regexp it is not correct, but regexps are not supported here, for that you need to use `mod_rewrite`. In short try this:

```
ProxyPass "/Proxy1/" "http://1.224.0.30:8080/dashboard/"
ProxyPassReverse "/Proxy1/" "http://1.224.0.30:8080/dashboard/"
```